# creating a file when a user signup

Tags: python, django

I need a file to be created when a user signs up.
below is my signup view.py in django:

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
  form_class = UserCreationForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  template_name = 'signup.html'
```

what should I do to a file be created at the same time when user signs up?

Comment: What do you mean by saying a file? Another model instance?

Comment: by saying file i meant file not model instance . I need a json file to be created when a user sign up in the webpage.

Comment: I need only one file to be created for each user. so that user could save some data to file @ruddra

Comment: i need to write some json data for everyb user @ruddra

Answer (score 0):

your problem is creating a file. your question is about how to create that file or is about when to use that code?

this is the code you need to create a file:

`f = open("guru99.txt", "w+")`

for more information have a look on this:

https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html

Comment: Actually i have to open the file in signup class. Is there any way to do so

Comment: Why don't you use the code above in any class you need?
you can also send the data which stored in the file as an argument.

Comment: yeah! thanks this worked. Will i be able to call this file in any other function outside the class

Comment: It could be done, you need to choose how to use it according to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your file generation code in post method of class which is going to be path of sign up click button.

```
class SignUp(view):
  #code
  def post(self, request):
      filename = request['user'] + ".txt"
      #if above doesn't work try this:
      #filename = str(request['user'])+".txt"
      f = open(filename, 'w+')
      f.write(request)
```

Comment: i tried this but i'am getting an error : ` unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'SimpleLazyObject' and 'str'` @Nagesh Mhapadi